# Scroll Bar settings

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a text box with a lot of text in an **Excel Worksheet**, so I have the vertical scroll bar. However, when you first open the document, the scroll bar is not visible. You have to click into the text box to see that it scrolls.

Is there any way to make the scroll bar visible as soon as the document is opened?

Also, when you click in the box, the scroll bar snaps to the bottom... how can I make it so that it stays at the top?

This is how my worksheet looks like.

[image]

Comment: What application is this?  Are you talking about a userform or?  Please clarify your question a bit.

Comment: If it in an Userform try this `TextBox1.SetFocus: DoEvents: TextBox1.SelStart = 0`

Comment: @TimWilliams this is in excel. I'm not super familiar with it so I don't know what you mean by userform. I inserted an ActiveX Text Box and have a vertical scroll bar turned on in the properties of that text box.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I just put that into the VBA?

Comment: @SiddharthRout This is my sample file - https://spaces.hightail.com/receive/sTP6uSsK6s

Comment: You need OPTION A from my answer below :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout that worked!! thank you so much!!!

Comment: You are welcome :) One small tip: Next time when you ask a question, include as much details as possible. You will have a better chance of getting answers quickly ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**OPTION A** *TextBox is in the worksheet*

[image]

You can achieve what you want by setting it in the `Workbook_Open` code. Change `Sheet1` to whatever sheet the textbox is in.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .TextBox1.Activate
        DoEvents
        .TextBox1.SelStart = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

---

**OPTION B** *TextBox is in a Userform*

[image]

Use the `UserForm_Initialize` event

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'TextBox1.Text = [a1].Value ' For testing

    TextBox1.SetFocus: DoEvents: TextBox1.SelStart = 0
End Sub
```

[image]